# How to let python/django to access postgres db without requiring sudo -u

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, django

Still new in the Linux / django / python / postgres installation.

I have install the latest kubuntu 11.04, installed the postgres and django packages.
I have created a django_login in postgres with a database django_db, for django to use.

When I am at the stage to create the base django framework in the database, I have some troubles.
It works fine if I type

`sudo -u django_login python manage.py syncdb`

but it doesn't work when I don't use the `sudo -u django_login`.
However, my account is superadmin in postgres and,
I have created a system account django_login and my account is part of this group.

what did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

You missed that you created the account in PostgreSQL to be used by a system account (`ident`). If you want an account to use a username and password via the PostgreSQL client library then you need to use one of the other [authentication methods](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/interactive/auth-methods.html).

Answer (score 1):

The easier way to let django log in to your Postgresql database is using passwords. Open up your pg_hba.conf file (/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/pg_hba.conf). Change the line

```
local   all   all   ident
```

to

```
local   all   all   md5
```

Now Postgresql will let django log in using username and password, instead of requiring the Unix builtin ident system.

Comment: @stephanef Did you restart Postgresql after changing the conf file?

Comment: Thanks, (sorry I didn't found a way to insert line breaks...) After restarting the postgres server, it worked just right. I also went further and made the change just for the account. pg_hba.conf has been changed like the following: [`local django_db django_login md5`]-[`local all all ident`] Note that the order is important, if all is first then it ignore the django specific handling.

Comment: @stephanef Yeah, that's right. Good job =)

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify in the settings.py file 127.0.0.1 as the database host. In this way django uses a different authentication method.